# Find the number of functions from $\{3,4,5\}$ into $\{a,b\}$

Tags: algebra-precalculus, functions

Find the number of functions from $\{3,4,5\}$ into $\{a,b\}$

My attempt:

$$\{(3,a),(3,b),(4,a),(4,b),(5,a),(5,b)\}$$

This is the set of all possible Cartesian product from $A\times B$.

How do I proceed further?

Comment: Any subset of that that doesn't send a number to two different letters is fine. How many subsets are there?

Comment: @ZainPatel, I didn't understand. What fo you mean?

Comment: Hint: If $f$ denotes such a function then how many possibilities are there for $f(3)$? Same question for $4$ and $5$.

Comment: @drhab, there are two possibilities for each! Isn't it?

Comment: Yes. So what can you conclude from that about the number of functions $\{3,4,5\}\to\{a,b\}$?

Comment: @drhab, is it $6$??

Comment: No. Not addition but multiplication.

Comment: @drhab, then its $8$!!

Comment: @Ramanujan The answer is $2^3 = 8$.  Keep in mind that in mathematics that $$8! = 8 \cdot 7 \cdot 6 \cdot 5 \cdot 4 \cdot 3 \cdot 2 \cdot 1$$ so it is best to avoid using explanation points after a number unless you mean factorial.

Answer (score 1):

$$\begin{array}{ccc}
3&4&5\\
\hline
a&a&a\\
a&a&b\\
a&b&a\\
&\cdots
\end{array}$$
Can you finish? And can you find a general pattern? How many functions are there from $\{1,2,\ldots,10\}$ to $\{a,b,c,\ldots,z\}$?

Hint: the set of functions from $A$ to $B$ is noted $B^A$.

Comment: No. Not til. !!!